# Customizing the line separating windows

Tags: window, customization, dividers

After

```
% emacs -q
```

```lisp
(split-window-right)
(scroll-bar-mode 0)
(fringe-mode 0)
```

there is still a pixel-wide line separating the two windows.  What is this
line called, and how can I change its width and colour?  Can I replace it with
a character such as `|`, as is used in the terminal?

Answer (score 4):

What you want to change is called the `right-divider`. By default you'll just see a vertical line.

Whether the right divider is shown or not is controlled by a frame-parameter called `window-divider`, which you can change by evaluating

`(window-divider-mode)`

You can call <kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-variable` for `window-divider-default-right-width` to change the default size, and <kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-face` for `window-divider` to change its colour. Note that changing the face will also affect the `bottom-divider` appearance.

Comment: customizing window-divider didn't do anything

Comment: I missed out the `(window-divider-mode)` step. Answer corrected

Comment: There is still a line there without window-divider-mode.  That's the line I'm talking about.

Comment: Yes, that's shown when you're not using window-divider-mode. I don't know of any way to get rid of it.

Comment: If you turn off the fringe, via `M-x customize-variable fringe-mode`, and then customize the variables `window-divider` to match the color of your window background, and `window-divider-right-width` to 1, (both in the customization group `window-divider`, the bar is 'invisible'

Comment: Or if you keep the fringe, just set the color of window-divider to match your fringe

Answer (score 2):

This is the `vertical-border`. You can set it like this:

```lisp
(set-face-foreground 'vertical-border "green")
```

I don't know if it's possible to set the width, any further customisation would probably be done using `window-divider-mode` which 'covers' the vertical-border when it is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

With `window-divider-mode` activated, you can set the divider width in your config.

```lisp
(setq window-divider-default-right-width 3)
```

It makes much easier to reorganize buffer sizes with the mouse, imho, but some people won't like that.