# DOOM themes: color face for line that divides buffers

Tags: window, dividers

I installed Doom themes on my Emacs.
I would like to know how to manually change the color face of the vertical line that divides different buffers. By default it has a dark color not very undistinguishable from the background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customizing the line separating windows](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43669/customizing-the-line-separating-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to add `window-divider` settings to a theme

This is how one customizes a theme ... For this example I am using `emacs -q` and will describe the steps for customizing `adwaita` theme.

1. `emacs -q`
2. `M-x customie-theme RET adwaita RET`.  Click on `customize` link.

[image: M-x customie-theme RET adwaita RET`]

3. The customization buffer shows all themed variables.  `adwaita` doesn't provide any customization for `window-divider` faces or variables.

[image: adwaita has no customization for window-divider]

4. Go to the end of the customization buffer with `ESC >`, and use `Insert Variable` and `Insert Additional Face` to add faces and variabes need.  You can also customize their values.

[image: Use Insert Variable and Insert Additional Face]

5. Go to the beginning of the customization buffer with `ESC <`, and press `Save Theme`.  This is what you will see

[image: Save Theme]

6. On save you will also see a message saying where `Emacs` is putting the new customization file.  In my case `Emacs` writes the theme settings to `/home/whitetrillium/.emacs.d/adwaita-theme.el`.
7. In the same session or different session, do a `M-x load-theme RET adwaita RET`.  This is what you will see. Note the `window-divider` settings have taken effect.

[image: Adwaita theme with window-divider]

8. FWIW, this is what the customization file for a `theme` looks like.

```lisp
(deftheme adwaita
  "Face colors similar to the default theme of Gnome 3 (Adwaita).
The colors are chosen to match Adwaita window decorations and the
default look of the Gnome 3 desktop.")

(custom-theme-set-variables
 'adwaita
 '(window-divider-default-bottom-width 3)
 '(window-divider-default-right-width 3)
 '(window-divider-default-places t)
 '(window-divider-mode t))

(custom-theme-set-faces
 'adwaita
 ;; Existing faces Snipped
 '(window-divider ((t (:foreground "red"))))
 '(default ((((class color) (min-colors 89)) (:background "#EDEDED" :foreground "#2E3436")))))

(provide-theme 'adwaita)
```

---

`adwaita` doesn't provide custom `window-divider`s.  But I see an entry for `modus-operandi`.  So, when you are using custom themes YMMV.

---

As an aside, I think,

1. `Emacs` should display the currently active theme(s) in modeline.  I frequently see people looking at screenshots, and asking "What theme?" is that ....
2. `M-x customize-create-theme` should interactively query for theme.  Right now, the interactive invocation takes no arguments.

If someone is reading this, and if it makes sense, and its worth your  while, please take the above requests to `emacs-bugs` or `emacs-devel`.

Answer (score 0):

To get this

[image: Window Divider Mode]

do this

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 '(window-divider-default-bottom-width 2)
 '(window-divider-default-places t)
 '(window-divider-default-right-width 2)
 '(window-divider-mode t))

(custom-set-faces
 '(window-divider ((t (:foreground "red")))))
```

---

`M-x customize-apropos-faces RET window divider`

Also look at

```lisp
(info "(emacs) Window Dividers")
```

which can be reached through `C-h r i window divider`

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is this variable specified also in the doom theme files?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make it thinner? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my previous answer.

Comment: Is it ok to use setq instead of custom-set-variables?

Comment: I always prefer to go with `custom-set-variabes` and `custom-set-faces`.  `Emacs` writes the `emacs-lisp` code for me, and I don't have to remember or learn the `emacs-lisp` syntax.  Btw, the answer to question is, in 99.99% of cases it is OK to use `setq` in place of `custom-set-...`.