# How to export all face settings to a elisp file?

Tags: faces, themes

Some custom themes use code to generate the face definitions programmatically, which uses other variables like [this](https://github.com/erikbackman/mindre-theme/blob/06e7e2401a79425b9c02bb44cb995a8e79077d68/mindre-theme.el#L271).

I'd like to export all plain face settings as if they are shown in the buffer created by `customize-face` to an Elisp file like

```lisp
    (custom-set-faces
     '(citar-highlight ((t :bold nil)))
     '(code-cells-header-line ((t :inherit font-lock-comment-face)))
     '(comint-highlight-prompt ((t nil)))
     '(diff-refine-added ((t (:background "#bbffbb" :inherit diff-refine-changed))))
     '(diff-refine-removed ((t (:inherit diff-refine-changed :background "#ffcccc" :strike-through nil))))
     '(telega-msg-heading ((t (:background "gray94" :family "FZYouHeiS"))))
     ;; ...
     )
```

with all variables evaluated and replaced by plain color strings, font names, etc. How can I do that?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the list of all faces using the function `(face-list)`.

The face information for each face is stored in the `face` property of the symbol of the face. This is a *plist* of properties and values, e.g. `(:background "LightGrey" :slant italic)`. Technically, a *plist* (or property list) is a list where the even elements are keys (`:background`) and the odd elements values (`"LightGrey"`).

One of the properties is special, `:inherit`. It takes a face or a list of faces from which it inherits properties from. If you is satisfied with printing `:inherit`, all you need to do is to print each element of the `face` property. On the other hand, if you want the values as the face is presented in the current frame, you can use functions like `face-foreground` to retrieve this information.

To complicate things even further, if you would like determine how the face would look in another kind of frame (e.g. a terminal frame) you will need to check all theme definitions... (This is a major undertaking, so I would recommend it.)

Anyway, there are plenty of ways to attack this, depending on what you want.

One package does a lot of these things is [face-explorer](https://github.com/Lindydancer/face-explorer), maybe you can find some tools in it which would help you, or at least see how to handle face attributes.

Answer (score 1):

1. `M-: (customize-create-theme 'user)`
2. In the resulting buffer you have the following options

   - Theme name
   - [X] Remove saved theme settings from Custom save file.
3. Then you can click the `Save Theme`

Play with the options, and one of that will do what you want.

See also [How to customize an existing theme, and create a new theme out of it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72557/31220).

---

You can replace `M-: (customize-create-theme 'user)` by M-: (customize-create-theme 'mindre), and give a new theme name of say `my-mindre` if you want.

---

*(What you want is not very clear to me.  One of the above suggestions will work, whatever by your need)*

Comment: Saving that file created by `(customize-create-theme 'mindre)` is what I want. Thank you!